How to use Pm2 for deferent Port in NextJS app
I Have Purchased A VPS For My Nextjs App
I Hosted one NextJs App in my VPS using pm2 Port 3000
Now I want to Host Another NextJs app in same VPS in Port 3001 the website show me 502 Bad Gateway nginx   error
I tried to Change port in pm2


 pm2 start npm --name "app2" -- start Port  3001



but the still not working
VPS From Hostinger
OS Ubuntu

Try this:
NODE_PORT=3001 pm2 start --name "app2" npm -- start 

